# Selective mongodb collection "replication"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to replicate specific documents in a mongodb collection from the master database to a local database. I know that this functionality is not natively supported by mongodb. Instead, what I would like to do is to have a service that queries the "master" database and writes the records to the local database. I haven't started coding this yet so the options are completely open. Ideally, I would like to be able to read from and write to this database and maintain consistency between this local and the master. Eventual consistency is fine as long as it is within about 5 seconds. I have a few questions about this approach.

1. Is this the best option for my end goal?
2. Is this practically achievable?
3. If so, how would I go about structuring this?

Comment: You need replicate specific documents or collection ?

Comment: @AlqamaBinSadiq specific documents. The documents will be chosen with the query {"company":"value"}.

Comment: I have to search for it. I implemented one scenario in which I was adding different collections in different databases not documents.